# Инжект в чужой процесс системы Windows

Tags: winapi, windows

Здравствуйте!

Какой самый безопасный способ инжекта своего кода в процесс другого приложения?
Например, комбинации:

> `1) OpenProcess -> VirtualAllocEx -> SuspendThread -> GetThreadContext -> SetThreadContext -> ResumeThread.`

и

> `2) OpenProcess -> VirtualAllocEx -> WriteProcessMemoey -> CreateRemoteThread.`

Палятся всеми современными антивирусами, вследствие чего, программа попадет в карантин, так как её антивирь посчитает за вирус. Какие у вас есть предложения по этому поводу? Спасибо!

Comment: А разве в антивирусе объявить программу доверенной нельзя ?

Answer (score 3):

Все документированные способы инжектов, конечно же, известны антивирусам и палятся ими, универсального способа НЕдокументироавнного инжекта, подходящего для всех аверов, попросту нет! Кто-то повышает права сплоитом и подгружает свой драйвер, кто-то юзает малоизвестные фнукции OLE.

Comment: Эх...я так и думал...